# Generate report from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like:

```
+====+========+========+
| Id |   name |  value |
+====+========+========+
|  1 |   a    |      7 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  2 |   c    |      7 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  1 |   g    |      1 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  2 |   c    |      2 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  4 |   g    |      5 |
+----+--------+--------+
|  6 |   t    |      4 |
+----+--------+--------+
```

I need to write two (2) queries to generate two reports, according to this two conditions:

> Report Output1=if id  and name same (id,name,val)
>   Report Output2=if id same but different name(id,name,val)

How to write those two queries?

Comment: Well, your conditions is not clear, can you explain more please.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions is not clear, but mybe this what you want:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(25), Value INT);
DECLARE @YourId INT = 1;
DECLARE @YourName VARCHAR(25) ='a';
/**/
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 'a', 7),
(2, 'c', 7),
(1, 'g', 1),
(2, 'c', 2),
(4, 'g', 5),
(6, 't', 4);
/*First query*/
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE ID = @YourID AND Name = @YourName;
/*Second query*/
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE ID = @YourID;
```

If you want the result of both queries in one result, then you can use `UNION ALL` as:

```
SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE ID = @YourID AND Name = @YourName 

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM @T
WHERE ID = @YourID;
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/WWED69810)**.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure, what OP wanted, but maybe it was something like this?

```
// records where id and value are the same
SELECT * FROM @T WHERE ID=Value;

// other records having the same ids as abobe, but DIFFERENT values
SELECT * FROM @T WHERE ID IN
 (SELECT ID FROM @T WHERE ID=Value) 
  AND Id!=Value;
```

Results:

```
    Id  Name    Value
     1  g       1
     2  c       2

    Id  Name    Value
     1  a       7
     2  c       7
```

Thanks to @Sami for providing the fiddle which I modified into this [DEMO](http://rextester.com/BTFC9615).

Comment: No problem :) btw OP didn't even reply to our comments.